# Practical example of superiority of randomized algorithm

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, random

I'm looking for an example to show my students of an algorithm for which randomization of some kind leads to better performance on average. And I don't want that randomization to be of the Monte Carlo sort. Rather, I want an algorithm whose randomization amounts to making a random choice instead of a deterministic one. So I guess, if I understand the terminology, I'm looking for a Las Vegas algorithm instead of a Monte Carlo one.

For example, Quicksort is $O(n\log n)$ on average, as is randomized quicksort. So this is of the type I want, the Las Vegas type, but the randomized version only performs better in the worst case.

More generally, I want a relatively simple example of a Las Vegas algorithm that, in practice, benefits from randomization.

Comment: Most likely a bit too complicated, but if only for the title: [Canadians Should Travel Randomly](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-662-43948-7_32).

Comment: I realize that maybe what I'm looking for can't exist because the average speed for a deterministic is the expected speed over random choices and  that randomness there might balance with the randomness in the randomized algorithm. If this is the case, please let me know.

Comment: How about a primiality test which starts by doing several quick Monte Carlo attempts to prove the input composite, and only switches to a deterministic test to deliver the coup de grace if the input survives all of those? The result is a Las Vegas algorithm, using Monte Carlo trials as a subroutine.

Comment: The Minimum Spanning Tree (MST) problem [may be a good fit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree#Algorithms).

Comment: I'm not sure a non-deterministic approach based on some random sequence of numbers can be (much) better than the deterministic one on the average, because it would mean that almost every random sequence is "not a bad" choice, hence the deterministic algorithm using one of those  sequences would "not be bad too", and the non-deterministic algorithm would be better than the deterministic one only in the worst case : when the specific sequence chosed by the deterministic algorithm fails.

Comment: @user1952009 Not sure how you'd derandomize in general... also, see the links above.

Comment: @ClementC. : in practice, you generate on your computer a pseudo-random sequence from a seed, simply choose a seed to choose a particular "random" sequence. if the obtained deterministic algorithm is bad on the average, I don't see how the non-deterministic can do (much) better ?

Comment: But picking a random seed and feeding it to a deterministic algorithm is *exactly* what a randomized algorithm is, at its core. (A randomized algorithm is merely a deterministic algorithm which takes, on top of its input, a randomly generated seed.) The problem is that to get a truly deterministic algorithm the way you suggest, you have to pick one of these seeds once and for all... and now, you run in trouble. (What if the seed you pick is not good? What if for each input there is a majority of seeds that are good, but no seed that is good for *all* inputs?)

Comment: @ClementC. : I agree, and that's not so easy to find such a problem with such conditions, and to prove that such a (deterministic) sequence of seeds that would be good for all inputs has to be non-computable.
(and in the problem you linked to, it seems the increase in performance is only a matter of constants, not so impressive ?)

Answer (score 1):

Look into "competitive on-line algorithms." There is no underlying assumption on the input data distribution, where the input is revealed online. The yardstick for measurement is the ratio of the total online cost to the optimal off-line cost (incurred if all requests are known in advance). This ratio, the competitive ratio, is always lower if a randomized on-line algorithm is used. That is, by using randomization, the expected value of the ratio (of online-to-offline costs) is never higher than that for deterministic algorithms. In essence, the ratio is measuring the worst case (ratio) possible, over all possible request sequences.